# Формы числительного восемью и восьмью в одном предложении

Tags: орфография, склонение, числительные

К примеру, мне нужно написать *... 888 журналами*.
Я могу написать *... восемьюстами восемьюдесятью восемью журналами*, либо *... восьмьюстами восьмьюдесятью восьмью журналами*. А если я напишу так: *... восемьюстами восьмьюдесятью восемью журналами*, то есть буду чередовать **равноправные** формы *восемью/восьмью* в одном предложении, то будет ли это являться ошибкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"А если я... буду чередовать равноправные формы *восемью/восьмью*..."

Форма *восемью* при склонении всегда стоит первой (а это **уже** показывает, что она предпочтительнее), поэтому о равноправности форм говорить никак нельзя.

Есть конкретное мнение: числительные восемь и восемьдесят в Т.п. сохраняют беглую гласную **е**: восемью, восемьюдесятью. Отсутствие беглой гласной характерно для разговорной речи: восьмью, восьмьюдесятью.

Есть статистика: в творительном падеже числительное *восемь* и образованные от него *восемьдесят* и *восемьсот* имеют вариативные формы с беглым и сохраняющимся гласным в основе: *восьмью / восемью* (по Основному корпусу 27/236), *восьмьюдесятью / восемьюдесятью* (6/13), *восьмьюстами / восемьюстами* (3/3).
[**Русская корпусная грамматика. 4.3.2.2**](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5#432)

Конечно, чередование разных форм в одном предложении ошибкой не будет, такое встречается. Но мне кажется, что стоит придерживаться какой-либо одной формы.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так кажется)